# How can we export 2 TB Teradata(Table Size) into Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, teradata, data-migration, teradata-sql-assistant, fastexport

We have used FastExport utility but it is not efficient to process that huge data .
Which should be best way to export that much data .We want the most efficent & fast way to do that .

Comment: Well, FastExport *is* efficient to process way bigger tables, but it's an old legacy utility, you should switch to *TPT Export* (can be even faster & supports exporting to Hadoop files)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is first. It will be interrupted because internet is not reliable for such big execution. So split the data with some archiving application like winrar and send it bulb by bulk